# Possible solutions to install when bios is locked

Tags: hardware, secure-boot

I purchased a second hand Lenovo ThinkPad T440s which is a wonderful piece of hardware the only issue is, is that it had secure boot enabled and the bios was locked. The owner did not remember his password and therefore I couldn't unlock it. I have read around this laptop and the only possible way to solve the lock is through changing the mobo which is not worth the extra money really.

So, as I don't have access to changing boot drives and secure boot being enabled is it possible for me to install Ubuntu onto my device? I would really appreciate if you could either provide guides or link some external resources.
P.S. I have separate computer if certain things will be needed to be done externally.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sure! Step 1. Replace the mother board. Step 2: Install Ubuntu normally.

Comment: Or get a refund from the previous owner. They sold you unusable equipment.

Comment: They have already changed their number and I can't get in contact with them anymore :( I realised this too late

Comment: Ubuntu can be installed with secure boot enabled. All you have to figure out is how to boot from your USB drive. On some laptops pressing F12 does the trick.